# redirect and force download

Tags: django, google-app-engine, attachment, custom-headers

this is my problem: I have some pdf files on a server, my Django web-application 
is hosted on another server (not the same of the pdf files). 
On my appplication i know the pdf files link on the other server. I want to download that pdf files through my application without read them on web server application.

I try to explane. If i click on download link, my browser shows the pdf into his internal pdf viewer. I don't want this, i want that on click on a button the user will download the file without open it on internal browser.

I looked here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment
but this is not a good way for me, cause it requires that I read the file inside my web-application and after return it to the user.

Is it possible??

Comment: Perhaps your users would prefer it if you let them decide how they want to view the PDF? Browsers have File->Save if they want to store it locally instead.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, sounds like the wrong tool for the job. You can't really "redirect" and modify the response header, which means using django just to set the `Content-Disposition` header would require you to stream the file through django, then have django stream it to the client.

Let a lighter weight web server handle that. If you happen to be using nginx, [here's an awesome solution](http://kovyrin.net/2010/07/24/nginx-fu-x-accel-redirect-remote/) that fits your scenario 99% (the 1% being it's rails setting the header that nginx is waiting for).

If all you want is to set the header and the file doesn't need django processing, it would be even easier to proxy!

If you are not using nginx, I would change the title to a web server specific question about proxying a file & setting headers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is right I'm not using nginx, my application is hosted on google app engine, i change the title. Sorry. However, I thought that is not possible to solve my problem, after the reading of your reply I'm sure that there's no way to obtain what I need.  

Maybe will exist any javascript tricks to do what i need?

Comment: No javascript. I've heard of hackish ways that work on some browsers, but for consistent, bullet proof save-as, you gotta set the headers which can only be done via server. Well then, in your case, I don't really know how google app engine works, but if you can download files temporarily I guess you can do it through django. I can't start to imagine whether there are any problems trying to stream IN and OUT at the same time, but you could definitely save to a temporary file and then serve the file to the client within a decent amount of time, assuming Google has fast in/out bandwidth

Comment: I'd look around to see if headers can be set in appengine -- I literally have no clue about appengine.

Comment: ok! Thank you for your help, I found another way to avoid the left click. Using jquery i created a button. If you left click the button, it shows a a modal message that explain the right procedure for download (right click and save as...). Maybe it is the only possible solution using appengine.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. I have solved it downloading the file to my server and then writing it to the `HttpResponse`
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse

def startDownload():
    url, filename, ext = someFancyLogic()
    request = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    # Was the request OK?
    if request.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    wrapper = FileWrapper(request.raw)
    content_type = request.headers['content-type']
    content_len = request.headers['content-length']

    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=content_type)
    response['Content-Length'] = content_len
    response['Content-Disposition'] 
        = "attachment; filename={0}.{1}".format(filename, ext)
    return response
```